# Excel query using Transfer Data from System i

Tags: sql, excel, ibm-midrange

I am looking for information on how I can use the Transfer Data from System i Add-In for Excel to only get data that equals the data in one of my columns (both sets of data are strings). Unfortunately, I cannot just get the entire contents of the System i table since it contains more than the maximum allowed in Excel. Thank you!

Additional information for clarification purposes:

I'm trying to get specific data from the iSeries table. If the field in the iSeries = column A, I want that data placed in column c.

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B     COLUMN C 
  100                     xxxxx  

on the iSeries table 

FIELD 1 = 40   FIELD 2 = ITEMDESC1  
FIELD 1 = 100  FIELD 2 = ITEMDESC2 
FIELD 1 = 500  FIELD 2 = ITEMDESC3
```

In this case it would place ITEMDESC2 into column C since FIELD 1 = 100
I just need to know if there is a way within the WHERE clause using the Data Transfer for System i to do this?

I hope this is clearer

Answer (score 1):

Data Transfer is a simple file transfer.  It isn't intended to make decisions on how to select DB2 data based on the contents of various cells in an existing spreadsheet.  As a workaround, you can upload the existing spreadsheet to DB2 and then use IBM i Navigator's SQL Script function, join the uploaded Excel table to your DB2 table and use CASE to put the proper field into the proper column.

```
select columna, columnb, case when field1 = columna then field2 else ' ' end
from excelupload join db2table on some_join_criteria
where some_record_selection_criteria
```

It seems easier to transfer the file to the PC and do the column manipulation in Excel.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I actually need the data from the i, take that data and update the Excel data, and then take the Excel data and update data within SAP. Was hoping for a little simplicity to do this but it looks like I may have to do the initial update in Access and resend it back through Excel so I can do a copy/paste into SAP. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Access can use ODBC, which should give you more flexibility when doing this sort of work.  Straight file transfers aren't really intended to implement business rules.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate Approach:**

You could write whatever query you like in an iNavigator RunSqlStm window.  Set the option to save results, before you run the query.  Once you run the query, you can save results in several formats, including Excel.  If there are too many rows for your version of Excel, then you can save it as a .CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new request
2. Fill in system name (Next)
3. Fill in table name (Next)
4. Click "Data Options..."

On this panel is a SELECT and a WHERE clause.  Put the cursor in the Where box, click "Details..." and create your query.  Click "Apply" and then "OK".

Comment: I know how to do that part. It's within the Where clause that I do not know how to include the column data. For example Where Column A, Row 1 = Field1, Column A, Row 2 = Field1, etc.

Comment: So the error you're getting is that there are too many columns for Excel to handle?  I thought it was too many rows.  Data is mapped from DB2 for i to Excel in the order you specify the fields in the Select panel.  Put Field1 first and it goes into Column A, Field2 second and it goes into column B.  If this isn't clear yet, please edit your question to put an example of the DB2 table layout you have and the Excel layout you want to get.

Comment: See edit to above question. Hopefully it's clearer of what I need. Thank you!